# vault for kubernetes (vault-operator)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to find a suitable vault to use for Kubernetes itself and apps that will run on containers. By far many resources point to Hashicorp vault. 
There exists a vault operator by CoreOS for that but it seems abandoned since April.

We run Kubernetes on AWS with EKS.

Any suggestions what would be possible choices to use? I'm interested a lot to see what are the top choices that are used the most today for this purpose.

Thank you!

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CoreOS Vault operator](https://github.com/coreos/vault-operator) is beta as of this writing. I would not recommend using it in prod yet. There's also a [Bootsport Vault Operator](https://github.com/Boostport/kubernetes-vault) but doesn't seem to be prod ready either.

IMO, as of now, you are better off running standalone Vault Kubernetes [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) or a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/). You can use something like [this](https://github.com/drud/vault-consul-on-kube) or [this](https://github.com/raravena80/kubeconsulvaultoss) to get yourself started. Note: still use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to setup [CoreOS Vault Operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/vault-operator)! using helm The Vault operator will provision the vault pods for us. But I found that is it difficult to add more configuration for vault. For example, if you want to integrate Vault with AWS KMS.

After considering, I decided to use [Vault](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/vault)! with Consul storage backend and AWS KMS. The vault pods will have consul agents running as  sidecar containers.

Here is a part of configuration

```
storage:
  consul:
    address: "localhost:8500"
    path: vault
seal:
  awskms:
    region: "us-east-1"
    kms_key_id: "XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ"
    access_key:
    secret_key:
```

Our usecase is that using vault to manage our dynamic secrets in k8s